# Ubuntu 12.04 wifi not getting connected, wicd network manager response - No wireless networks found

Tags: 12.04

I have tried connecting to WiFi in my Dell Vostro laptop, distribution is Ubuntu 12.04 LTS. The `wicd` network manager shows `No wireless networks found.`

Output of `lsusb&&lspci` is:

```
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 8087:8000 Intel Corp.  <br/>
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub  <br/>
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub  <br/>
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub  <br/>
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 0c45:6a04 Microdia   <br/>
Bus 001 Device 004: ID 0bda:0129 Realtek Semiconductor Corp.   <br/>
00:00.0 Host bridge: Intel Corporation Haswell-ULT DRAM Controller (rev 0b)  <br/>
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation Haswell-ULT Integrated Graphics Controller (rev 0b)  <br/>
00:03.0 Audio device: Intel Corporation Haswell-ULT HD Audio Controller (rev 0b)  <br/>
00:14.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation 8 Series USB xHCI HC (rev 04)  <br/>
00:16.0 Communication controller: Intel Corporation 8 Series HECI #0 (rev 04)  <br/>
00:1b.0 Audio device: Intel Corporation 8 Series HD Audio Controller (rev 04)  <br/>
00:1c.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 8 Series PCI Express Root Port 1 (rev e4)  <br/>
00:1c.2 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 8 Series PCI Express Root Port 3 (rev e4)  <br/>
00:1c.3 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 8 Series PCI Express Root Port 4 (rev e4) <br/>
00:1c.4 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 8 Series PCI Express Root Port 5 (rev e4)  <br/>
00:1d.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation 8 Series USB EHCI #1 (rev 04)  <br/>
00:1f.0 ISA bridge: Intel Corporation 8 Series LPC Controller (rev 04)  <br/>
00:1f.2 SATA controller: Intel Corporation 8 Series SATA Controller 1 [AHCI mode] (rev 04)  <br/>
00:1f.3 SMBus: Intel Corporation 8 Series SMBus Controller (rev 04)  <br/>
06:00.0 Network controller: Broadcom Corporation BCM43142 802.11b/g/n (rev 01)  <br/>
07:00.0 Ethernet controller: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller (rev 0c)  <br/>
08:00.0 3D controller: NVIDIA Corporation GF117M [GeForce 610M/710M/810M/820M / GT 620M/625M/630M/720M] (rev ff)  <br/>
```

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! ;-) Could you please give us a bit more information like: what WiFi hardware you're using? Please provide the output to `lsusb&&lspci`.  Please [edit] your question and add this information...

Comment: Please [edit] your question so that the next person reading your question does not have to read all the comments (and you can only have a maximum of 10 comments).  Also please read the [editing help](http://askubuntu.com/editing-help) to improve the readability of your question.

Comment: I have edited my original question. Any luck on resolution?

Comment: Yes!  Look at the above link and follow it carefully.  This is the best resource we have on this site for Broadcom drivers.  If anything would go wrong there, just leave a comment here and then we'll take it from there.  **;-)**

Comment: That is the link I followed to remove hard block but still my WICD network manager throwing error "No wireless networks found." Please help.

Comment: I've asked for expert expert help as this seems to be a PCI-based broadcom adapter. Help will arrive in about 4-8 hours...

Answer (score 0):

Why did you install Wicd in preference to Network Manager? Did you remove NM? Please verify which driver is installed:

```
lsmod | grep -e wl -e b43
```

And verify that the hard block is solved:

```
rfkill list all
```

What messages are given if you try to scan?

```
sudo iwlist wlan0 scan
```

Substitute eth1 for wlan0 if that is your wireless interface. Also, what is your kernel version?

```
uname -r
```

I am not sure any solution is even possible for kernels before 3.13.

You have a 3.5.0-xx kernel. It may or may not be possible to download and install this: https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/raring/amd64/bcmwl-kernel-source/6.20.155.1+bdcom-0ubuntu1 as well as the prerequisite *dkms* package: https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/raring/amd64/dkms

This assumes you have a 64-bit install; find out:

```
arch
```

If you have a 32-bit install, I will do additional research and edit this answer.

If, on the other hand, you installed Ubuntu 14.04 LTS, it should work out of the box, either 32- or 64-bit.

Comment: 3.5.0-58-generic

Comment: Please see my edit above.

Comment: Errors were encountered while processing:
 bcmwl-kernel-source

Comment: Please tell us the exact error; it may be correctable.

Comment: I tried to install the two .deb files today morning to reproduce the errors, strangely, did not encounter errors but still wicd manager showing "No wireless networks found."

Comment: What errors, if any, are seen when you: sudo iwlist wlan0 scan. Substitute eth1 if your interface is eth1.

Comment: sudo iwlist wlan0 scan
[sudo] password for shaswati: 
wlan0     Interface doesn't support scanning.

Comment: What is your interface? iwconfig. If it is eth1, then: sudo iwlist eth1 scan.

Comment: The issue is with the scan argument I guess. Output is a follows - sudo iwlist eth1 scan
eth1      Interface doesn't support scanning : Invalid argument

Comment: Output of iwconfig
eth0      no wireless extensions.

eth1      IEEE 802.11abg  ESSID:off/any  
          Mode:Managed  Access Point: Not-Associated   
          Retry  long limit:7   RTS thr:off   Fragment thr:off
          Power Management:off
          
lo        no wireless extensions.

Comment: Hi...Any resolution found yet?

Comment: May we see: rfkill list all and also: dmesg | grep -e wl -e eth1 As the result is probably lengthy, post it here and give us a link: http://paste.ubuntu.com

Comment: Pasted both outputs, u can access the output in the following url - http://paste.ubuntu.com/10428966/

Comment: "ERROR @wl_cfg80211_scan : WLC_SCAN error (-22)" That's why it doesn't scan and see networks. As I suspected, the version of bcmwl-kernel-source that matches your running kernel, 3.5.0-xx, won't properly drive your device. I suggest you upgrade to Ubuntu 14.04 LTS where it will work from the outset.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion. Would soon upgrade to 14.04 LTS